# The -F attribute for "ls" command

Tags: ls

I'm finishing LFS101x so I'm rather new to Linux. Towards the end of the course, the author says:

> You can view the full list of configuration files by typing **ls -lF** /etc/cups.

This is obviously about printing configuration files but the question is what the attribute `F` changes for the `ls` command.

`man` for `ls` says the following:

> append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries.

However, I was not able to see the difference between `ls -l` and `ls -lF`. I attached a screenshot of the output of the commands:

[image: Ls command output]

I don't see anything appended as stated in the manual. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This isn't a Linux Q&A site, but a Ubuntu one (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)  As you're asking about Linux, SE *Unix & Linux* maybe more appropriate, as currently I don't see anything on-topic for this site (no on-topic OS & release is mentioned)   *You also didn't provide release details, there are slight variations as software changes, the `man` pages adjust for those changes, and by not providing your release details we can't provide specific details that match your unstated release*

Comment: ps: Did you look at `info ls` & more than just the reference (summary) page?

Comment: You can't see the `/` at the end of the directory entries there?

Comment: @guiverc Just because the question doesn't explicitly mention Ubuntu doesn't automatically make it off-topic. It is a generic Linux question that also applies on Ubuntu, so it's on-topic and shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot shows what you're asking.

With `ls`, a directory is printed (in blue) as `directory`. With `ls -F` it's printed as `directory/`

Symlinks will be printed as `symlink@` with `ls -F`.

Colors - as can be seen in your screenshot - has largely replaced `-F` for many people, as they indicate the same thing, in a more convinient form.